# How would you calculate the sum of a binary tree recursively with given input tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree, nodes

**Hi! I need help finding a way to calculate the sum of a binary tree recursively. I have put what I have been working on but I am still really confused. Please, any help would be appreciated.**

Define a recursive function named sum, which takes a binary tree as
an argument, and returns an int – the sum of all the node values in the tree. For
the tree on bottom for example, the function returns 35.

[image]

```
def sum(t: TN) -> int:
    if t == None:
        return 0
    else:
       return [sum(t.value)for v in t]
```

Answer (score 1):

1.What we have here:

Given the root of tree.

Find the sum of the whole tree.

Using recursive.

2.Recall what is recursive?

```html
A recursive function is a function that calls itself during its execution. This enables the function to repeat itself several times, outputting the result and the end of each iteration
```

3.

We need a base, which will terminate the recursive function, otherwise it will infinite loop.

Once we have base case, now we need to start execution of rest.

4.

For a Binary Tree, it has root, (optional) left child, (optional) right child. 
We can choose root as a base case, because this is the start point of a binary tree.

```java
private int sum(TreeNode root) {
     //1. base case
     if(root == null){
        return 0; 
     }
     //2. go bigger
     else { 
       return root.val + sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
     }
}
```